# Why do Muslims believe God is in literal up direction?

Tags: islamic-basis

I read an article on a website called islamqa where they were giving several reasons of how God is in **upward** direction i.e when Muslims pray, they lift their hands upward or when something bad happen, they look upward.

But that according to me is very childish and doesn't even make sense because:

1 - The earth is round and rotating which means, what is up right now won't be up after 2 hours and for every region on the earth, the up direction is different.

2 - The up direction doesn't even exist! If you go 10 Km above the earth, it is space and there is no up/down/right/left in space.

Some scholars such as Salih Al Fawzan, and [others](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pi87Ne4EzGs) believe earth is not rotating!

So the question is, do Muslims actually believe God is in literal up direction?

Answer (score 1):

Just to make you correct, **Muslims don't believe that Allah (God) is in the upward direction** but we **Muslims believe that Allah is everywhere**. Even some Islamic scholars strictly stop Muslims to give a direction (especially the upward) for Allah Almighty.

(Wallah o Tala Aalam, Warasoloho Aalam)